# How to manage multi-sections collectionview using NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: swift, core-data, uicollectionview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm creating a collectionView based gallery, that should display images from Core data.

I'm using `NSFetchedResultsController` to fetch and populate data. 
My model looks like that:

```
+-----------+-------------+
| Attribute | Type        |
+-----------+-------------+
| data      | Binary Data |
+-----------+-------------+
| date      | Date        |
+-----------+-------------+
| isPinned  | Boolean     |
+-----------+-------------+
```

The initializing of the FetchedResultsController :

```
private func initializeFetchedResultsController() {
    let request = NSFetchRequest<BaseMediaEntity>(entityName: BaseMediaEntity.className)
    let dateSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: false)
    request.sortDescriptors = [dateSort]
    request.fetchBatchSize = 20

    let moc = DBManager.manager.dataStack.managedObjectContext
    fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: request,
                                                          managedObjectContext: moc,
                                                          sectionNameKeyPath: "groupByMonth",
                                                          cacheName: nil)
    fetchedResultsController.delegate = self

    do {
        try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
    } catch {
        fatalError("Failed to initialize FetchedResultsController: \(error)")
    }
}
```

And `groupByMonth` is just monthly formatted string from date,
so the gallery is sorted by months.
My question is :

I need to implement a pinned section of all the images that have been set to `isPinned = true` at the top of the collection view.
Is it possible to set multiple sectionNameKeyPaths? or How can I solve this problem? thanks!

Comment: Probably easiest to have two FRCs with mutually exclusive predicates (`isPinned == true` and `isPinned == false`).  Populate section 0 with the first, and the remaining sections with the second.  Just remember to adjust the indexPaths for the second FRC: what it believes is section 0 corresponds to section 1 of the tableView, etc.

Comment: @pbasdf Thanks for your comment. I found another solution,  Instead of passing `groupByMonth` at `sectionNameKeyPath` I created another computed property called `groupByType` to check if `isPinned` is set to true then return `"isPinned"` else return `groupByMonth`. Also, I added sort descriptor for `isPinned`.
What do you think?

Comment: Yes, that’s a good solution.  You should add it as an answer.